# Where should this render to MTKView while loop go in UIKit?

Tags: uikit, metal

Regarding [this](https://img.ly/blog/build-a-simple-real-time-video-editor-with-metal-for-ios/) tutorial...

It describes how to load frames from a video file and draw them one after another to a Metal view.

There is a `while` loop that iterates over each frame and calls `draw` on the view...

```
while sampleBuffer != nil {
    
    ...

    displayView.draw()

    ...
}
```

Where should this loop go? I have tried it in `viewDidLoad` and after a delay and lots of print outputs it only seems to show the final frame. It's as though you can't see updates to a view before `viewDidLoad` has finished.

Comment: Correct... you do not ***see*** anything until `viewDidLoad` has finished. I don't know what the result is supposed to be (I haven't worked my way through the linked tutorial), but you could try putting that in `viewDidAppear()` or run it on a button tap, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose I would put it in `viewWillAppear(_:)` or `viewDidAppear(_:)`. However, this is the first time I've seen a draw command in a super tight loop like that, and it seems less than ideal.

If you would like to control the draw manually, I would recommend the use of a `CADisplayLink` instead. The purpose of `CADisplayLink` is it is timed to be in sync with the system update of the screen. You can also set a preferred frame rate, which is nice.

```
weak var displayLink: CADisplayLink?

func createDisplayLink() {
    displayLink?.invalidate() // in case existing timer
    let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(update(_:)))
    displayLink.add(to: .main, forMode: .common) 
    displayLink.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30 // Optional set desired frame rate 
    self.displayLink = displayLink
}

@objc func update(_ displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
    displayView.draw()
}

func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // You can create it earlier, but I prefer here 
    createDisplayLink() 
}

func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // Stop rending when view disappears
    displayLink?.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. This is a side project. I got it working copying the loop to `update(_ displayLink: CADisplayLink)`. I needed to make `sampleBuffer`, `trackOutput` and `reader` class properties. Now I have low-level video. Awesome. Thanks for your help.